# JS function in R/Python markdown

Tags: javascript, python, html, r-markdown

I'm trying to add custom JS function inside R markdown html file.
I'm expecting to see code block folding when I knit.

The function worked when I knitted with R:
`{r setup, include=FALSE} knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, warning = FALSE, message = FALSE)`

knitted with R

[image: 1]

However, when I try Python in R markdown, it doesn't work.

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::knit_engines$set(python = reticulate::eng_python)
```

<div class="fold s">
```{python}
print('hello, world')
```
</div>
````

knitted with Python

[image: 2]

Can anyone help me, please?
Below is the entire code that I used...

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::knit_engines$set(python = reticulate::eng_python)
```

```{js, echo=FALSE}
$(document).ready(function() {

  $chunks = $('.fold');

  $chunks.each(function () {

    // add button to source code chunks
    if ( $(this).hasClass('s') ) {
      $('pre.r', this).prepend("<div class=\"showopt\">Show</div><br style=\"line-height:22px;\"/>");
      $('pre.r', this).children('code').attr('class', 'folded');
    }

    // add button to output chunks
    if ( $(this).hasClass('o') ) {
      $('pre:not(.r)', this).has('code').prepend("<div class=\"showopt\">Show Output</div><br     style=\"line-height:22px;\"/>");
      $('pre:not(.r)', this).children('code:not(r)').addClass('folded');

      // add button to plots
      $(this).find('img').wrap('<pre class=\"plot\"></pre>');
      $('pre.plot', this).prepend("<div class=\"showopt\">Show Plot</div><br style=\"line-    height:22px;\"/>");
      $('pre.plot', this).children('img').addClass('folded');

    }
  });

  // hide all chunks when document is loaded
  $('.folded').css('display', 'none')

  // function to toggle the visibility
  $('.showopt').click(function() {
    var label = $(this).html();
    if (label.indexOf("Show") >= 0) {
      $(this).html(label.replace("Show", "Hide"));
    } else {
      $(this).html(label.replace("Hide", "Show"));
    }
    $(this).siblings('code, img').slideToggle('fast', 'swing');
  });
});
```


<style>
.showopt {
  background-color: #004c93;
  color: #FFFFFF; 
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle !important;
  float: right;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.showopt:hover {
    background-color: #dfe4f2;
    color: #004c93;
}

pre.plot {
  background-color: white !important;
}
</style>

<div class="fold s">
```{python}
print('hello, world')
```
</div>
````

Comment: Why not pass this whole javascript code along with styles in a html file as a `header-include`?